# How can Xcode debug files not in the working project

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, unreal-development-kit

I'm using Unreal Engine to build a game, most parts are done in Visual Studio in windows, except build the iPhone release.

The Xcode project contains nothing but an Info.plist and the Game.app, which is build with external gcc & g++ commands. I can choose "Run without Building" in XCode to run and debug on real device.

As a result of that project structure, I cannot easily navigate between file, the only thing I found for now is click "Pause" in debugging window, then use "Step In", "Step Over" and "Step Out". There for I'm limited to where the app paused and related code.

I can set break points by clicking on line numbers, but gdb break command does not work. So I can't find files from breakpoints.

So that leads to my problem, how can I navigate in files that actually built the app when they are not in the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can actually use `break filename:linenumber` to add a break point, program will break there, even if it does not work at Xcode's break point view.

I think it's also how everybody else debug there UDK games.